# C# Selenium 4.0 Proxy Authentication with Chrome Driver BiDi APIs freezing

Tags: c#

when I use the code block below, my browser does not go to the address.

```
var options = new ChromeOptions();
options.Proxy = new Proxy {HttpProxy = "1.1.1.1:12345", SslProxy = "1.1.1.1:12345", Kind = ProxyKind.Manual};
var driver = new ChromeDriver(ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService(), options, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2));

NetworkAuthenticationHandler handler = new NetworkAuthenticationHandler()
{
    UriMatcher = d => true,
    Credentials = new PasswordCredentials("proxy_user", "proxy_pass")
};

var networkInterceptor = driver.Manage().Network;
networkInterceptor.AddAuthenticationHandler(handler);
networkInterceptor.StartMonitoring();

driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://stackoverflow.com/");

networkInterceptor.StopMonitoring();
driver.Quit();
```

it works if i disable this code:

```
networkInterceptor.StartMonitoring();
```

but this time it doesn't verify. what can I do?

Relevant source: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/bidi_apis/

Comment: Encountered something very similar, have you ever figured it out?